# Amend count to string if duplicates exist, without amending non-duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some invoice numbers, some are duplicate and others are not:

```
Invoice Number
123
123
1
1
123
A
B
C
D
123
```

Where there's a duplicate, I'd like to add a `_#` where the `#` refers to the "index" of the duplicate reference.

Expected output:

```
Invoice Number
123_1
123_2
1_1
1_2
123_3
A
B
C
D
123_4
```

This is almost do-able with `COUNTIFS()` (placed in `B2`):

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A2)>0,A2&"_"&COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2),A2)
```

Except that formula will leave the first duplicate as is, and then the second duplicate has `_2`:

```
Invoice Number
123
123_2
1
1_2
123_3
...
```

I'd also like that first `123` to have `_1`.  I tried this formula, but it amends `_1` even to unique values:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)>0,A2&"_"&COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2),A2)
```

There must be something simple I'm overlooking.

Comment: How about `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,A1)=1,A1,A1&"_"&COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1))`. In your last formula, `>1` would have done the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put thid in an unused column to the right and drag down.

```
=A2&IF(COUNTIF(A:A, A2)>1, "_"&COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A2), "")
```

Comment: [Duhhh](https://i.imgur.com/2o1AMCy.gif)!  Thanks so much, I don't know how I didn't think to just do `A2&...` at the start.  Cheers! :D